# Different Results from Using MATCH with FTS and LIKE with Wildcard in SQLite

Tags: mysql, sqlite, full-text-search

The query I used for FTS MATCH is: `query = "'^"+request.args.get("q")+"*'"`
where q is a place name or zipcode (e.g.: "90210", "NY", "LA", ...).

> When looking up zipcodes it can produce ("90210", "90211", ..) when q="902" (desirable behavior). But, when looking up area codes, it can produce ("NY", "Nye", ..) when q="NY" (undesirable behavior).

I want the result of a MATCH query to produce a similar result of using LIKE with a non-FTS table where the query is: `query = "'^"+request.args.get("q")+"%'"`

> When looking up zipcodes it can produce ("90210", "90211", ..) when q="902" (desirable behavior). But, when looking up area codes, it only produces ("NY") when q="NY" (desirable behavior).

Comment: What about checking the search term and dynamically choosing the query?

Comment: Apparently the "%" wildcard does nothing when MATCH is used.

Comment: @raina77ow That's actually pretty clever. But surely there must be another way to do it with SQL wildcards or maybe FTS tokenizers?